# Own CSS don't override Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

Strange bootstrap 4 (alpha6) behaviour.

My main.scss looks like that:

```
$fa-font-path: "../assets/font-awesome/fonts/";

@import '../assets//bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "../assets/include-media/dist/include-media.scss";
@import "../assets/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300,700,400';
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel';


@import "helper/fonts";
@import "helper/variables";
@import "helper/helper";
@import "global";

@import "partials/header";
@import "partials/footer";
@import "components/navigation";

@import "views/index";
```

and in my global.scss I just got:

```
body {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: #000 !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: $font-family-sans-serif;
}
```

but somehow the included scss from bootstrap-4 overrides my own css code. 
I installed b4-a6 with bower, compiled with gulp (the usual way) and uploaded with remote-sync (atom.io). I can open and read the proper css file on the server, my own css is even included in the compiled file, at the bottom, so apparently the compiled file gets properly uploaded but the browser doesn't read my own css.
With bootstrap 3.2 everything workes fine.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**
Firefox (latest) and Chrome (latest beta) same behaviour. Safari (latest public beta) reads the css fine and the website is good.

**EDIT 2:**
Here's my gulp css file:

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    config     = require('../config'),
    sass       = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    prefix     = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    header     = require('gulp-header'),
    concat     = require('gulp-concat'),
    watch      = require('gulp-watch'),
    notify     = require('gulp-notify');

// Compile our css and push it to the public webfolder
gulp.task('css_main', function () {
    gulp.src(config.themePath + 'scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(notify({
            title: "SASS",
            message: "Compiling main.scss ..."
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', function(error) {
            notify().write(error);
        }))
        .pipe(prefix('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
        .pipe(header("/* This file is generated, do not edit by hand! */\n"))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../css/maps', {
            includeContent: false,
            sourceRoot: '../scss'
        }))
        .pipe(notify({
            title: "SASS",
            message: "Compiled: <%= file.relative %>"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.themePath + 'css/'));
});
```

Comment: As far as I know this should work with Bootstrap 4 as well. Could you just try using a stronger selector just like `html body { ... }`

Comment: same behaviour. I even added the global.scss as one of the first after the boostrap.scss and still nothing in chrome and firefox. Even with the stronger selector.

Comment: Maybe you've got something wrong in your gulp config? Using Bootstrap 4 (Alpha 6) I can just adjust my body tag as I want to: https://jsfiddle.net/ubnqhvad/

Comment: Same here, but just in Safari. Other browser don't read my file. I'll try to include the .css from a CDN.

Comment: Yes, without the scss files and included as style tag in <head> from CDN it works fine. Strange.

Comment: Not sure if something else overwrites your global.scss. You could also try moving that import to the end. If that fails too I assume you've got something wrong with your gulp config.

Comment: Can we see this live somewhere?